# Why is this expression evidently differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across this expression while reading a journal:

> $\hat{m}_{h}(\tau)=\frac{{\displaystyle {\scriptstyle {\displaystyle \sum_{s=t}^{t+l+d-1}}K_{h}(\tau-s)P_{s}}}}{{\displaystyle \sum_{s=t}^{t+1+d-1}}K_{h}(\tau-s)},\qquad t=1,\dots,T-1-d+1
> $
>
> where $P_s$ are real numbers and $K_h(z)$ is a Gaussian kernel.

The author then says that it is clear that $\hat{m}_{h}(\tau)$ is a differentiable function of $\tau$.

By inspection, it is not evident to me that the $\hat{m}_{h}(\tau)$ is differentiable with respect to $\tau$. I know the definition of differentiability in terms of limits and was going to evaluate the required limit but this function is looks complicated so I am unsure how to proceed.

The fact that the author did not provide any workings to justify the differentiability suggests to me that it is obvious and I do not need to evaluate the limit.

How can I notice that $\hat{m}_{h}(\tau)$ is differentiable with respect to $\tau$ without working from first principles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both top and bottom are finite sums of differentiable (in fact infinitely differentiable) functions, thus both differentiable, and the bottom is everywhere non-zero as a sum of Gaussians all of the same sign. Thus their quotient is differentiable. This follows from the standard sum, product, quotient laws of differentiation.